# UK visitor visa validity end date

Tags: uk

UK visitor visa allows you to stay for 180 days for say a 2-year period between 01/01/2018 to 31/12/2020. Does this mean you need to leave the UK on or both 31/12/2020?

I know that on a Chinese visa the "to" date is the last day you are allowed to enter China. You can for 90 days afterward. I presume this is not the case for a UK visa?

Comment: Note that it is not automatic that you may stay for 180 days; if you applied and said you want to stay for 2 weeks and then actually stay 180 days, you may be refused entry in future.

Comment: @user16259 do they even record what you say about how long you are intending to stay?

Comment: Yes they do. First you give that in written on your application. Then you give that in written when you reach the border

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to leave the U.K. on or before the last date of your visa’s validity. The last date is when you must leave. It’s not the last date for entry. If you enter on the last date you must leave on the same date.

Unlike your example for China, or USA for that matter.